# GZipStream effectivness

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I am trying to save big UInt16 array into a file. positionCnt is about 50000, stationCnt is about 2500. Saved directly, without GZipStream, the file is about 250MB which can be compressed by external zip program to 19MB. With the following code the file is 507MB. What do I do wrong?

```
GZipStream cmp = new GZipStream(File.Open(cacheFileName, FileMode.Create), CompressionMode.Compress);
BinaryWriter fs = new BinaryWriter(cmp);
fs.Write((Int32)(positionCnt * stationCnt));
for (int p = 0; p < positionCnt; p++)
{
    for (int s = 0; s < stationCnt; s++)
    {
       fs.Write(BoundData[p, s]);
    }
}
fs.Close();
```

Comment: What's it like if you compress it *using gzip* externally?

Comment: external gzip  gives about 19.5 MB; bzip2 little less than 8MB

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what version of .NET you're running on. In earlier versions, it used a window size that was the same size as the buffer that you wrote from. So in your case it would try to compress each integer individually. I *think* they changed that in .NET 4.0, but haven't verified that.

In any case, what you want to do is create a buffered stream ahead of the `GZipStream`:

<strike>// Create file stream with 64 KB buffer
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 65536);
    GZipStream cmp = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress);
    ...</strike>

```
GZipStream cmp = new GZipStream(File.Open(cacheFileName, FileMode.Create), CompressionMode.Compress);
BufferedStream buffStrm = new BufferedStream(cmp, 65536);
BinaryWriter fs = new BinaryWriter(buffStrm);
```

This way, the `GZipStream` gets data in 64 Kbyte chunks, and can do a much better job of compressing.

Buffers larger than 64KB won't give you any better compression.

Comment: .Net 4, uncompressed is 250MB, compressed 1-short at a time (regardless of buffer) is 411MB, compressed 2500-shorts at a time is 165MB.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But it does not help. The result with larger buffer is about the same (517MB - I also changed the content of the array to speed up experiments). Also there is a problem with the name fs you have used in your example - fs is the BinnaryFormatter (this is my fault, names fs and cmp used by me are confusing).

Comment: @danatel: My mistake. I put the buffer on the wrong end. See my correction that uses `BufferedStream`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped - the result with my data and 65k buffer is 57MB; with initial content (the same UInt16 repeated over the buffer) 3MB, with my data and 20MB buffer the result is 50MB.

Comment: A 20MB buffer made a big improvement? They must have made some major changes for .NET 4.0. I'll have to give `GZipStream` another look.

Comment: Is this optimisation (using a BufferedStream) true for Decompression as well?

Comment: @rolls yes, the buffered stream will improve decompression performance.

Comment: What if the byte array is already entirely in memory? That would not be a benefit then would it?

Comment: @rolls The buffered stream improves the speed of writing to or reading from disk. If you're working strictly in memory, then the buffered stream would probably slow you down.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, which is not apparent to me during a quick read of the GZip implementation in .Net, the performance is sensitive to the amount of data written at once. I benchmarked your code against a few styles of writing to the `GZipStream` and found the most efficient version wrote long strides to the disk.

The trade-off is memory in this case, as you need to convert the `short[,]` to `byte[]` based on the stride length you'd like:

```
using (var writer = new GZipStream(File.Create("compressed.gz"),
                                   CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    var bytes = new byte[data.GetLength(1) * 2];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < data.GetLength(0); ++ii)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, bytes.Length * ii, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    // Random data written to every other 4 shorts
    // 250,000,000 uncompressed.dat
    // 165,516,035 compressed.gz (1 row strides)
    // 411,033,852 compressed2.gz (your version)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do not know what array content did you use for your benchmark. My content is pretty regular and can be compressed down to 8MB. 165MB is too much.

Comment: `data[ii, jj] = random.Next()` for half the data (~125MB). I was merely pointing out the differences in compression using 1-short  versus 1-row at a time.

Comment: That explains the difference - random noise is not as compressible as my quite regular data. Thank you for your help.